# how do i install horizontal scrolling UI (for an image gallery) on wordpress (with no coding skills)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, horizontal-scrolling

i'm setting up a personal website to showcase my portfolio, and wanted to do that with a horizontal scrolling UI. i've purchased hosting and a domain, and i've already installed WP, but i couldn't find a theme that does what i want.

basically, i want my gallery to look like this format theme (https://panorama.format.com/#9). i looked up the source code, and it seems it uses jscrollpane (http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/).

how difficult would it be to recreate the format theme in wordpress using jscrollpanel considering i've got no coding experience? is jscrollpane even the right thing for what i'm trying to do?

i'd appreciate any help, especially tutorials that might help me achieve the horizontal gallery effect i've shown as an example.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

without coding skills, it's difficult but if you want, look with Swiperjs (Example + Sources Code)
Demo : https://swiperjs.com/demos/120-slides-per-view-auto.html
Source code : https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/120-slides-per-view-auto.html

There must be a plugin that does what you ask.
https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-fullscreen-responsive-slider/ ?

Comment: shame, i guess i'll see if i can hire a cheap front-ender to do it for me. thanks for the tip.